# How do I flatten results from my SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns the following table:

```
Year    IsFunded     NotFunded
2003    Null         4
2003    3            Null
2004    Null         2
2004    8            Null
```

So I need:

```
SELECT Year, IsFunded, NotFunded
FROM
(
    --myQuery that returns unflattened results
)
```

I just need one row for each year.
like:

```
Year    IsFunded     NotFunded
2003    3            4
2004    8            2
```

Comment: I question table design here. Why not maintain a boolean column, `IsFunded` and a value column, `Qty` or `Amount`? Then conditionally query into two columns the `Amount` based on true/false of `IsFunded`. This avoids storing Nulls and unambiguously defines columns.

Answer (score 4):

Use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT t.Year, MAX(t.IsFunded) AS IsFunded, MAX(t.NotFunded) AS NotFunded
FROM 
(
    --myQuery that returns unflattened results
) AS t
GROUP BY t.Year;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace null with 0 while sum and just add group by year, like below

```
           with MyQuery(Year,IsFunded,NotFunded) as (
          select 2003,Null,4 from dual union
          select 2003,3,Null from dual union
          select 2004,Null,2 from dual union
          select 2004,8,Null from dual
          )
          select year,sum(case when IsFunded is null then 0 else IsFunded end) as IsFunded,
          sum(case when NotFunded is null then 0 else NotFunded end) as NotFunded
          from MyQuery group by year
```

Output

```
        YEAR ISFUNDED  NOTFUNDED
        2003     3         4
        2004     8         2
```